# Howto check sync with kovan testnet is complete or not?

Tags: go-ethereum, testnets, kovan

I am trying to sync with Kovan testnet,

```
docker run --name eth -p 8546:8546 -v ~/ws-002-chainlink/ws00-docker-geth-ropsten:/geth -it ethereum/client-go:stable --testnet --syncmode light --ws --wsaddr 0.0.0.0 --wsorigins="*" --datadir /geth
```

Here is the status after 3 days of running ...

[image]

**Will there be any print like sync complete ?**

Answer (score 0):

You can check progress with command `eth.syncing`(from the `geth console`), if syncing is on going you must see:

```
{                         
  "currentBlock": xxxxxxx,  
  "highestBlock": xxxxxxx,  
  "knownStates": xxxxxxx,   
  "pulledStates": xxxxxxx,  
  "startingBlock": xxxxxxx  
}
```

`false` means that your Geth is up to date and is not currently syncing. As long as the command `eth.syncing` returns an object, your node is syncing.

When process is complete you'll see `INFO [xx-xx|xx:xx:xx] Imported new chain segment ...` entries in the log.